# Automation tool for mobile application(IOS and Android)

Tags: automated-testing, android, ios

Which testing tools are currently used for mobile application testing for both IOS application or Android application?

What skills are required for mobile application testing automation?

Comment: What are your needs/requirements?  Have you done some investigation into current options?  Why did they not meet your needs?

Answer (score 1):

1. Appium
2. Calabash
3. MonkeyTalk
   .. all of them are support for IOS and Android applications.

But I recommended **Appium**. It is an open source project for cross-platform test automation. Essentially, it is an HTTP server managing WebDriver sessions. It supports tests in any framework and in any language that can create an HTTP request. No app code needs to be modified for testing. Any test is suitable to run on either iOS or Android on real devices or emulators. It supports native, hybrid, and web apps.

following skills are also required for a good MobileApp QA:

1. Programming Skills
2. Familiar with mobile operating systems because
   when doing test scenarios for automation, the tester has to know whether the step can be simulated with the provided API of the mobile operating system.
3. Familiar with telecommunications domain
   knowledge for determining the test environment matrix. For instance,
   for a video conferencing application, then the network, SIM card,
   and phone network capabilities play a big part in the test platform matrix.
4. Familiar with the general telephony functions and their
   relationship (e.g. SMS, WAP, GSM). For example, incoming, dial,
   rejected and answered states. With this knowledge and their interaction with the other telephone functions, test cases with state transition test methods can be designed properly.

Comment: thank you for your wonderfully commend, it help me very much. Could you please suggest me which programming skill need for Appium.

Comment: I would prefer Python, because of its simplicity.